# Why is Chrome making my Windows meta key sticky?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have finally seen this issue not stop when Chrome was closed.  On that basis I am now more confident that I am seeing something much more like [Control key acts as if it is stuck periodically](https://superuser.com/questions/956049/control-key-acts-as-if-it-is-stuck-periodically)

Original question was as follows.

---

This is such a weird behaviour I am almost certain the short answer is "it is not" but please hear me out.

I have a Windows 7 laptop that for the past couple of years has been working fine.  In the last month the machine periodically acts as it some meta or control key is pressed.  When in this weird state; pressing <kbd>u</kbd> brings up the Windows Ease of Access Center window, I cannot use backspace and various other keys all do odd things when you expect input.  This is not limited to entering text into the Chrome application, but any application.

Why do I point my finger at Chrome?  The problem immediately resolves if I close Chrome.  When I start Chrome again things are OK for a while (few days).

I have lots of Extension installed but only a few enabled.  The most recent one I added was Amazon Assistance for Chrome.  I also have enabled: Cashback Notifier - TopCashBack, Chrome Daltonize!, Google Hangouts, Google Play Music, Pinterest Save Button, Regex Search, Save to Pocket and Webroot Filtering Extension.

This sounded like a Windows sticky keys problem.  I have checked that all aspects of that feature and disabled according to the GUI menus.  I have even turned off various sub-features inside these disabled one and toggled things on and off.

Like I said it is weird.  Any help or suggestions of things to try besides closing and opening Chrome every few days would be gratefully received.

Comment: I have finally seen this issue not stop when Chrome was closed.  On that basis I am now more confident that I am seeing something much more like https://superuser.com/questions/956049/control-key-acts-as-if-it-is-stuck-periodically