# Windows 10 Behaves as if Ctrl Held Down

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, virtual-keyboard, ctrl

As of late, my desktop computer has begun behaving ~30-60 minutes after reboots as if I am holding down the control key indefinitely.  I have seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/956049/control-key-acts-as-if-it-is-stuck-periodically), but its workarounds and solutions did not assist me, nor did googling as what I found there was generally the same list of solutions.  The only thing I've found that "resolves" this is rebooting, and even then, it is only briefly.  The problem seems to begin only when I am actively using the computer, but does not *appear* to coincide with an actual press of the Ctrl key.

I have tried unplugging and replugging my keyboard.  I've disassembled my keyboard and verified that the button is not physically stuck.  I've tried using software to rebind the left control to right control (which I ordinarily never use) and it still persisted.  I've run Microsoft's keyboard diagnostics which returned nothing.

I've pulled up the on-screen keyboard and verified that both control keys appear to be held down indefinitely.  If I tap either key on the physical keyboard, those keys flash off momentarily on the on-screen keyboard, but then go back to being highlighted a moment later, as if Windows somehow still thinks the key is being held down somewhere else.  I've found that if I can get the timing right (which usually requires 20-ish attempts), I can get a keystroke on the physical keyboard to slip in while Ctrl not highlighted and actually use the key as if Ctrl was not being held.

Manually clicking the key on the virtual keyboard seems to do nothing at all.  Using software to spam key up/down messages does not resolve it.

Sticky keys, filter keys, etc, are all off.

Windows is up-to-date and security scans have detected nothing.  I'm approaching the point where I'm fearing I'll need to repair/reinstall Windows.  Is there any other action I can take before that point?

Comment: Is it a laptop or desktop computer? You could try a different OS to see it is a hardware or software problem, e.g. [Ubuntu Live](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0) will run off a USB stick.

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/956049/control-key-acts-as-if-it-is-stuck-periodically

Comment: Andrew: I'll try that, thanks!
David: No, but I've software-disabled the control key inputs from it, so unless the driver for it is just spitting out garbage, shouldn't matter.  I'll try that as well though.
Harry: I saw that as well, but it was similar to what I linked in the question, so I didn't link it too.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue, and I was able to resolve it by:

1. opening the on screen keyboard (OSK.exe)
2. selecting Windows button + L to lock my computer
3. logging back in

I have no idea why that solved the issue, but it did.

Got this from:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows-key-stuck-down-not-physically/42a9ccd3-5362-4930-98e1-257c5b4ae668

Answer (score 0):

I recently started having this exact issue, though I believe it's actually the WIN key that becomes "stuck". I fixed it by pressing WIN + L, which would lock my computer. Upon logging back in, it seems fixed. I have had friends who only just started having the same issue as well, I suspect a windows update may have done it.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue with my HP All in one desktop , i.e the ctrl key appeared to be pressed randomly or stuck indefinitely without me actually physically pressing the key. I tried changing the batteries of my wireless keyboard , updated windows , updated my BIOS from the HP website , updated the drivers for the keyboard and mouse etc , but nothing seemed to work. Then I contacted HP support and they said to run the HP Hardware diagnostics. I restarted my computer , pressed ESC key repeatedly that took me to a menu of different options from where I selected the HP Hardware diagnostics option by pressing F2 key. Under this option there was "Component Test" menu and under it "Keyboard" test.
It basically brought up a virtual keyboard diagram and asked me to press the corresponding highlighted keys on my keyboard to check if all keys where responding and everything was working as it should be.
After doing this and restarting my computer , the problem seemed to be solved
NOTE :- This probably works only for HP products but I am sure there are similar approaches to other brands . Try to search how to perform a Keyboard component test for your respective platforms / brands

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen if I press Ctrl+Fn+Home, and pressing Fn+End clears it.

I don't know if this is a windows feature or a keyboard feature, so ymmv.

Answer (score -1):

I've recently faced with this issues. As this happened after trying to sanitize the keyboard with an alcoholic fabric pad, I doubt the issue may be related to it. I think one small drop of alcohol may have got in the keyboard and before disappearing has caused some issues.
Mine went away after a 10-minute break and a restart.

Answer (score -1):

Win+L, then logging back in fixed it for me, but I can no longer open the Start Menu. Bit ridiculous for Windows to have a bug that stops you from using Windows