# The Ctrl keys are stuck

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, usb, keyboard

The two <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys of both my laptop and USB keyboard seem to be stuck. They are pressed automatically. I have tried restarting the Windows, unplugging and replugging them, uninstalling and reinstalling the driver. But nothing works.

The only way to solve the problem is by reinstalling Windows. It doesn't work with normal reinstallation. I have to do a clean installation. But after just a few days, the bug returns.

I now have disabled the keys using SharpKeys and have assigned the left windows key as a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. The worse thing is that I installed Ubuntu to get rid of this problem. I have dual boot on the same hard disk. But Windows not only glitched itself. It also has glitched the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys in Ubuntu. I have detected it by doing this:

I used Ubuntu for some days. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys were creating problems. So, I reinstalled Windows, and the problem went away in both Windows and Ubuntu. Then, when the bug occurred again in Windows after a few days, I logged into Ubuntu and saw that it also affected Ubuntu.

Now, what should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Does the USB keyboard work with a different machine without problems?

Comment: Yes, the USB keyboard works fine with a different machine. It works also in the current machine but only if I clean reinstall windows

Comment: Have you tried another USB keyboard?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. I have even used the onscreen keyboard. The onscreen keyboard even displays that the ctrl keys are pressed.

Comment: This question has some good answers: https://superuser.com/questions/956049/control-key-acts-as-if-it-is-stuck-periodically