# My keyboard kept typing gibberish. I solved the issue, but I don't know how. [windows10]

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, cmd.exe

Until today morning, my keyboard kept typing gibberish, for no particular reason. However, upon going to Command Prompt and typing the command ipconfig/flushDNS, the problem was mysteriously solved. I don't know how that helped. Anyone who can explain?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I have experienced a logically "stuck" control/alt/windows key in my keyboard, despite the physical keys not being stuck. Usually clicking the offending key again will solve the issue. There is a possibility this was fixed by itself because when opening the terminal window, you used some key combination which was comprised of the offending key (e.g. Win+R to open the run console to execute powershell/cmd)

Next time you will know if this is the case if pressing certain keys will result in the "special key" + clickedkey action instead of the standard clickedkey action itself.

There is a more in depth related answer here:
[Control key acts as if it is stuck periodically](https://superuser.com/questions/956049/control-key-acts-as-if-it-is-stuck-periodically/1243900)

Comment: This does not really answer the question about how the command fixed it.

Comment: I edited the answer so a clear connection is made between the question and the answer, thanks!

Comment: My keyboard kept typing prefix "^[". Don't know why but this solves the issue.